# Executar instrução apenas se 5 condições forem verdadeiras. Javascript

Tags: javascript

Qual comando devo usar para executar uma instrução apenas se 5 condições forem verdadeiras ?

Por exemplo Em portugol :

```html
Se 1 +1 = 2 e 
   2 +2=  4 e 
   4 +4=  8 e 
   5 +5= 10 e
   6 +6= 12 então faz isso.
```

Como faço isso em javascript ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simples, você utiliza o `if` com ou sem `{` e `}`. Parece meio óbvio, mas para quem está começando não é tão assim, mas a maioria dos comandos nas linguagens de programação tem uma boa tradução para o português e a melhor forma de entender (aka. decorar) um comando é sabendo o real significado dele; No caso do `if` em tradução livre significa `Se`.

O mesmo é válido para loops e outras estruturas de decisão, isso sem contar nas palavras chaves (*keywords*).

Respondendo sua pergunta, dá pra implementar dessa forma:

```js
if ((1 + 1) == 2 && (2 + 2) == 4 &&
    (4 + 4) == 8 && (5 + 5) == 10 &&
    (6 + 6) == 12) {
    // faça alguma coisa aqui
    alert('Este é um alerta');       
}
```

Comment: fiz dessa forma mai daí num funcionou achei que tava errado, agora vejo que o erro é outro...Vlw man

Answer (score 6):

A resposta para sua pergunta é bem simples, porem é mais conveniente você entender os conceitos primeiro para que você possa resolver esse e outros problemas com condicionais no futuro usando JavaScript ok?

Em [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com) (link para um tutorial prático da linguagem e não a definição dela em si), condições são manipuladas através de um bloco condicional chamado `if`.

O `if` funciona de seguinte forma:

```
if (expressao) {
 // executa se a expressão for verdadeira
}
```

O `if` espera simplesmente uma *expressão* que, obrigatoriamente, precisa retornar uma valor booleano verdadeiro (`true`) ou falso (`false`).

Um exemplo prático:

```
if ( (2+2) == 4 ) {
  console.log("2+2 é igual a 4");
}
```

O que aconteceu acima foi o seguinte, a expressão `(2+2) == 4`, basicamente, avalia se (2+2) é igual a 4, se isso for verdade, uma mensagem será escrita no console do browser.

O operador `==` serve para verificar se o valor da esquerda é igual ao da direita, se for, ele retorna `true`, senão, ele retorna `false`.

O `if` tem também dois blocos complementares (não são obrigatórios):

`else`: Caso a condição que o `if` espera, retornar um valor que não é verdade, um bloco else (caso esteja implementado), será executado.

```
if ( (3+2) == 4 ) {
  console.log("3 + 2 é igual a 4");
}
else {
  console.log("3 + 2 não é igual a 4");
}
```

`else if`: Deve vir logo após um `if` ou `else if` (sim, é possível usar vários `else if`), é executado caso a condição anterior não seja verdade.

Exemplo:

```
if ( age <= 13 ) {
  console.log("É apenas uma criança");
}
else if (age >= 14 && age <= 18) {
  console.log("É um adolescente");
}
else {
  console.log("É apenas um adulto");
}
```

Perceba o `&&` acima, ele é um operador lógico de conjunção que avalia a expressão a esquerda e a direita dele, se ambas tiverem o mesmo valor booleano, ele retorna `true`, senão ele retorna `false`.

Com esse operador, você pode testar várias condições da seguinte forma

```
var condition1 = (1+1) == 2 // condition1 vai ser true, porque o operador == vai dizer que (1+1) é igual a 2

var condition2 = 2 < 5 // o < compara se o número a esquerda é menor do que o da direita, se sim, retorna true, senão, false

if (condition1 && condition2) {
  console.log("as condições 1 e 2 são verdadeiras")
}
// a variável condition1 por sí só, será avaliada como booleana, logo não é necessário escrever condition1 == true se eu quiser saber se ela é verdadeira
else if (condition1) {
  console.log("a condição 1 é verdadeira")
}
else if (condition2) {
  console.log("a condição 2 é verdadeira")
}
else {
  console.log("as condições 1 e 2 são falsas")
}
```

Outras formas de avaliar condições no JavaScript são com operador tenário `?:` que é usado normalmente quando se quer atribuir um valor dependendo de uma expressão booleana e o `switch` que pode substituir o `if` em casos em que você tem várias opções de tomada de decisão de acordo com um determinado valor.

Comment: Sua intenção foi a melhor, mas sua resposta não respondeu a pergunta, concorda ? Veja a resposta do @Uilque Messias, embora ele não tenha entrado profundamente no tema, ele respondeu e não sei se por eu ter feito igual achei correta...Mas agradeço da mesma forma...